# how can I create class instance variables in ruby

Tags: ruby, class, methods

I have the following code:

```
def self.test
  # clear out all the other products so we have a clean slate
  BF.delete_all_products

  BF.puts_and_file("\n\n## ==== scenario #{@scenario_timestamp} =====\n\n")
  BF.puts_and_file "endpoint: #{@baseUrl}"

  @aggregating_PRP = BF.create_aggregating_rate_plan

  pro_plan_id = BF.create_product(@create_pro_20_5_5)['id']
  biz_plan_id = BF.create_product(@create_biz)['id']

  @pro_20_5_plan = BF.create_rate_plan(pro_plan_id, @create_rate_plan_for_pro_20_5_5)
  @biz_plan = BF.create_rate_plan(biz_plan_id, @create_rate_plan_for_biz_monthly)
end
```

I would like to replace all those `@instance` variable assignments by doing this:

```
def self.create_products
  @aggregating_PRP = BF.create_aggregating_rate_plan

  pro_plan_id = BF.create_product(@create_pro_20_5_5)['id']
  biz_plan_id = BF.create_product(@create_biz)['id']

  @pro_20_5_plan = BF.create_rate_plan(pro_plan_id, @create_rate_plan_for_pro_20_5_5)
  @biz_plan = BF.create_rate_plan(biz_plan_id, @create_rate_plan_for_biz_monthly)
end
```

But it doesn't seem to work.  The variables in the create_products method aren't available to other class methods .

I'm actually not super clear how to work with methods/classes and variables in principle.

Comment: for clarification.  @aggregating_PRP should be available to any class method I call within `test`

Answer (score 0):

Instance variables (with a single `@`) in class methods or instance eval for a class are stored in the the class.

```
class Book
  def self.default_opts=(opts)
    @default_opts = opts
  end

  def self.reset_default_opts
    @default_opts = {}
  end

  def self.default_opts
    @default_opts || reset_default_opts
  end

  def initialize(opts)
    @opts = self.class.default_opts.merge(opts)
  end
end

Book.instance_variables # => [:@default_opts]
```

Comment: Hm, it doesn't seem to behave this way.  `@default_opts` doesn't appear available in subsequent methods.

Comment: Hmm. Could you post a gist of your code or do you maybe have it in a public repo somewhere? It may be a problem with loading. Are you autoloading the class somehow?